# How can i update email column with appending some text in a particular place in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update my email column like this

```
  |id (int)  | email(varchar)         |    is_subscribed(boolean)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  1        |  abc@gmail.com         | true
 |  2        |  def@gmail.com         | false
```

update email where id=1 
after the update , an updated email will be like `abc-cancel@gmail.con`
`cancel` is string which i want to append

Answer (score 3):

This what you are describing:

```
update t
   set email = 'abc-cancel@gmail.com'
   where id = 1;
```

Actually, I suspect that you want to insert the `-cancel` into the email.  I strongly discourage this.  You should be storing such information in a different column rather than destroying information in your database.  But if you really must, you can use `replace()`:

```
update t
    set email = replace(email, '@', '-cancel@')
    where id = 1;
```

After you do this, you will not be able to match emails in different tables, different databases, or provided from third-parties.  Seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: can i pass a variable in place of '-cancel@' @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @bala . . . You can pass a variable into an update the same way you would pass a variable into any statement.  So, yes, in the second version you can.